# ERROR ITMS-90512: Invalid sdk value... 8.2 is higher than maximum allowed value of 10.3?

Tags: ios, watchkit, apple-watch, ios-extensions

Trying to upload a binary, which includes a watch app.  The error I'm getting (which I wasn't getting a couple days ago) is the value provided for LC_VERSION_MIN_IPHONEOS for the watchkit extension is 8.2 which is greater than the maximum allowed value of 10.3... apparently 8.2 > 10.3?

I'm updated to the latest XCode, 8.3, that didn't fix the problem.  Tried changing the iOS deployment target for the watch app and extension, no apparent effect on the message.

Comment: Sounds like LC_VERSION_MIN_IPHONEOS is not being defined as a number and, more likely, is defined as a string.  Then, of course, a string beginning with a 1 would be less than a string beginning with an 8.

Comment: lol @ 8.2 > 10.3 - Only Apple can rewrite math. I wonder what they think 1+1 is?

Comment: What is your deployment target set to?  Is it the same for the app and all extensions?

Comment: @LouFranco target is set to 8.0 for phone and 8.2 for watch app/extension

Comment: @GlennRay that might be.  Any way to change the string?  Is it just the deployment target?

Comment: @adam I am having the same issue.  My CI machine always cleans deriveddata, so the answer won't help me.  Looking for clues on what may be similar in our projects.  My theory right now is ITunes connect bug.

Comment: @LouFranco it's strange because it seemed to be working until very recently, and nothing really changed.  I also submitted a TSI to Apple, we'll see what they say.

Comment: Have you submitted with 8.2 before?  This is our first submission with 8.2 and Swift 3 and we were wondering if it was related to that.

Comment: My previous submission was in xcode 8.0, no problems until today.  I saw there was an xcode update, 8.3, and thought that might be related, but that didn't work either.

Comment: I have the same, two days ago build was accepted and now same project has this issue

Comment: I am facing this issue too. Seems like an issue with Xcode itself. It was working in 8.2.1 but not now in 8.3

Comment: Cleaned and Build the code, still facing the same issue. Intermittently successfully uploaded, but becomes invalid binary when it was submitted for review.

Comment: I don't think it's related to Xcode. I compiled my app with Xcode 8.1 3 days ago and sent to review without any problems. Today I tried the same thing and got this error. I think they messed up something on their side.

Comment: I am having this problem as well. Happens with both Xcode 8.2.1 and 8.3. It does seem to be an iTune Connect validation problem.

I did get it to upload last night without the error, but it has never appeared in the "Processing" list or the list of builds I can submit for review. If I try to upload again I get the original error.

Comment: We are having the same issue with an app that still supports WatchOS1. Two days ago we were able to upload builds without issues.

Comment: It might indeed affect only WatchOS1, the only thing I haven't tried is updating to WatchOS2, since I don't want to right now.

Comment: I am also having this issue too, same with guys above, I have an watchOS1 target..

Comment: My binary that was getting rejected just got uploaded. Anybody else had luck, is it fixed?

Comment: no. the error is still active:(

Comment: @btschumy Hi Bill  Hope they'll fix it soon rdar://31389233

Comment: I was able to upload and get into internal beta, but it failed to go to external beta with the same error (8.2 > 10.3)

Comment: I uploaded a new binary and I was able to submit for beta review (which is further than I have gotten)

Comment: I was able to put my app for review with watchOS1 in the build. A couple of hours ago I got the ITMS-90512 error after pressing the submit button. Now it worked and the app is waiting for review. I think Apple fixed the issue.

Comment: works for me as well!

Comment: Confirmed! Its fixed!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

*Update: it's fixed!*

I have submitted a bug to Apple. They have replied that they are aware of the problem and have people looking into it. They will contact me when they have resolved the issue.  I'll post an update here when they do.

Comment: Yeah, I got that today as well. 2 days ago when I first submitted the ticket they didn't take me seriously, they were asking for a video showing it happen...

Comment: They have still not responded and I will be away on business for a while.

Comment: Are Apple sure that this problems is due to them, or whether we?

Comment: @dar512 Can you post rdar for your report? Mine is rdar://31389233 (no feedback from Apple yet)

Comment: I uploaded a new binary and I was able to submit for beta review (which is further than I have gotten)

Comment: same.. im going to select this as the answer

Answer (score 7):

This is not related to Xcode 8.3, the error is in the Apple validation process. I had an app in review (no problems in uploading it) that got rejected because the user provided for login had expired. I made no changes to the app, just activated the user and submitted. I have the error now.

Edit: I can also confirm that if Watch support is removed everything goes well.

Answer (score 3):

**EDIT:** This is problem on Apple side and **nothing** to do with Xcode. This is only effecting apps with WatchKit.

I just uploaded one my apps today that has a watchkit extension. Try this, it may or may not help.

- Xcode -> Product Clean
- Xcode -> Quit
- In a console terminal do > rm -rf  /Users/your_mac_user/library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/*
- Relaunch Xcode and project
- Go to your Xcode -> Build Settings for your iPhone app and make sure its set to 8.0 for debug and release

[image]

- Now go to both your watch and watch extensions and make sure the Build setting is set to 8.2
- Archive and upload again.

[image]

Comment: Tried a full clean, deleted derived data, didn't work.  My deployment targets are the same as yours too, 8.0 for iphone, 8.2 for watch/extension.

Comment: @Sam, what version of Xcode are you on? Do you use Swift? If so, what version?

Comment: @Sam didn't help for me too, I am using Xcode 8.3, before tried with Xcode 8.2.1

Comment: @Sam B, Was this WatchOS1 or newer?

Comment: @Ecuador that was for watch OS 3

Comment: @SamB Right, so judging from the comments, it seems to be just Watch OS 1 affected...

Answer (score 3):

EDIT: Although successfully uploaded to iTunes Connect, when trying to submit a Testflight beta build, still got rejected by the same message

> Invalid sdk value. The value provided for the sdk portion of
>   LC_VERSION_MIN_IPHONEOS in XXX.app/PlugIns/XXX WatchKit
>   Extension.appex/XXX WatchKit App.app/XXX WatchKit App is 8.2
>   which is greater than the maximum allowed value of 10.3.

[image: Error]

Guess Apple's still working on it...

---

I am having this issue earlier, also with a watchOS1 target in my project.

I've tried to upload the binary again few minutes ago, no more warning shows, and passed the processing of iTunes Connect.

Everybody having this issue should give it a try!

Comment: @PauloRocha, johnny: Have either of you been able to submit the binary for App Store review yet? (just regular, not beta)

Comment: @LouFranco Nope ;(, no luck. still got rejected when submitting review for App Store / Testflight external build. I've submitted a DTS ticket few minutes ago, hope Apple can fix this issue soon. It's really delaying our schedule.
(Perhaps everybody having this issue should submit a DTS ticket? maybe it could speedup the procedure of fixing this issue, Apple will give a ticket credit back if the issue is caused by Apple itself, so don't be afraid of using DTS ticket.)

Comment: I agree -- also open a RADAR.

Comment: @LouFranco, No. I just tried again and got the same error submitting for review. Then it becomes invalid binary. Its taking too long for them to correct this. I hope they realize it was not only in the upload process.

Comment: @Johnny, I opened one too. What puzzles me it that with this error no one should be able to submit apps with support to apple watch. All the bells should be ringing at Apple.

Comment: @PauloRocha, Johnny: I uploaded a new binary and I was able to submit for beta review (which is further than I have gotten)

Comment: @PauloRocha Thanks, I've submitted with same binary, it works!

Answer (score 2):

I was submitting with an old Xcode version, I thought that was the problem, so went to the latest and it gives me the same message, that I am submitting for 8.2 which is higher than 10.3.

Now, here is where it gets really crazy. I said, OK, maybe there is an issue with 8.2, so I switched my minimum target to 8.3, cleaned, archived, submitted. I STILL GET THE MESSAGE ABOUT 8.2!!!

I exported the package I am uploading:

```
otool -l MyApp.app/MyApp |fgrep --after-context=3 LC_VERSION_MIN_IPHONEOS
  cmd LC_VERSION_MIN_IPHONEOS
cmdsize 16
version 8.3
    sdk 10.2 
--
cmd LC_VERSION_MIN_IPHONEOS
cmdsize 16
version 8.3
    sdk 10.2
```

I grepped both the package and my project directory, there is no friggin' "8.2" string anywhere. The same app without the watch extension validates fine. It seems they have broken the watch submissions (at least WatchOS1), which is something they should have noticed, yet I emailed support 2 days ago with screenshots and they were unimpressed, telling me to send them a video if I want my ticket to be processed! Take 1 minute to look at the upload log, I gave you app ID and timestamp, how hard is that?

Edit: It seems I installed the previous version of xcode, there is one newer out, but it also doesn't fix the issue, the problem appears to be on the Apple side...

Edit 2: The binary that has not been going through since the day before yesterday, just got uploaded. Maybe it is fixed?

Edit 3: But then you get the message in itunes connect when you try to submit the app. So it seems they are working on it, not completely resolved yet.

**Edit 4: SUCCESS! Successfully submitted, waiting for review!**

Answer (score 1):

**Apple fixed this bug yesterday**. You can use the same binary. There's no need to make any changes.

Answer (score 0):

I deleted the watch-related targets, and uploaded successfully.

Answer (score 0):

If you download a new version of Xcode, make sure to switch to it:

```
sudo xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode_11.6.app/Contents/Developer
sudo xcodebuild -runFirstLaunch
```

Ecuador's answer about using `otool` is a great tip to make sure the SDK is correct before you submit.

Answer (score -1):

I too had the same issue. Removed the watch app and did the upload. It has been accepted for review. So looks like the issue is with the validation of the watchkit extension. Will submit the app again with the watch app once this issue has been taken care of by Apple.

Comment: This should be a comment and not an answer.