# Xcode 9 fails to upload to itunes connect

Tags: xcode, app-store-connect, xcode9

I've recently being unable to upload archives compiled with Xcode9 to itunes connect. The error I'm getting is:

```
iTunes Store Operation Failed
ERROR ITMS-90512: "Invalid sdk value. The value provided for the sdk portion of \
LC_VERSION_MIN_IPHONEOS in MyApp.app/MyApp is 11.0 which is greater than the \
maximum allowed value of 10.3."
```

It looks like similar problems were an Apple bug in the past:

[ERROR ITMS-90512: Invalid sdk value... 8.2 is higher than maximum allowed value of 10.3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43105469/error-itms-90512-invalid-sdk-value-8-2-is-higher-than-maximum-allowed-value)

but it might also be that Xcode 9 should not be used for publishing. However that worked in the past.

Comment: Try changing the SDK value to `10.3`... otherwise use TestFlight.

Answer (score 0):

The new release (9 beta-2) has fixed this issue

Answer (score 0):

For those that look for an answer where XCode 9 GM doesn't recognise you as a member of a team, just export the build and upload it using standalone Application Loader.